# Update a nested-list document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, patch, datamodel

Consider:

```
{"configs":
         [
          {name: "config1", list: [{name: "ele1.1", list:  [1, 2]}, {name: "ele1.2", value: "true"}]},
          {name: "config2", list: [{name: "ele2.1", list: [3, 4]}, {name: "ele2.2", value: "true"}]}
         ]
}
```

I want to insert 5 in the list of `ele1.1` under `config1`. How do I do it?

And if this one is not a good design for this kind of insert, how could I redesign to make it easy, in my application?

I have this kind of nested structure as deep as five levels.

Comment: @Action this is pretty straightforward querying and updating, and you can find lots of answered questions on this site on this topic if you search for them.

Comment: @VinceBowdren hey, but when it comes to nested list, insert would not be that simple to me, can you show me how to do it in one query?